# How do I CFINCLUDE without creating a cached template in /WEB-INF/cfclasses/?

Tags: coldfusion, include, coldfusion-9

Are there any solution or alternative ColdFusion tag to include static text file without creating template cache under /WEB-INF/cfclasses ?

The problem is I have dynamic pages growing over the time.
Each page need to include one single static file.

e.g.

```
<cfinclude template="mapping/static_1.txt> for page 1
<cfinclude template="mapping/static_2.txt> for page 2
<cfinclude template="mapping/static_3.txt> for page 3
....etc.
```

Since the number of pages are growing to 2000 pages, it cause the server down as the system generate 2000 cache tempaltes which exceed the server limit.

I can ask hosting support to extend the limitation but that will not be the long a term solution for dynamic pages that growing over the time.

Obviously, there is **no calculation required** as the file to include is static text (.txt) which contain static HTML tags (no script involve).

**Is there any alternative tag apart from `<cfinclude >`** that will just
 show the file content without binary calculation and cache creation?

**Or is there any solution to prevent server from caching .txt file?**

Sorry for question that may simple but I'm new to CF here.
Your pointer would be really appreciate.

Cheers
Chanon

---

my hosting support do not recommend disable caches all together.

Anyway, I came out with a simple solution using `<cffile>` instead of `<cfinclude>`.

When using `<cffile>` server will not execute each lines and create cache. Instead, it just grab the whole chuck of file and put it in variable.

Comment: @TimPost While there are details in the main body which are specific to the user, the question title itself is generic enough to warrant this question remaining open. CFInclude vs FileRead is something that a lot of ColdFusion developers lack knowledge of.

Comment: Re-opened after a minor edit, based on the answers, some Googling and advice left in comments.

Answer (score 5):

Why use CFINCLUDE if those are static HTML files? Use FileRead() for example (or longer version with FileOpen/FileReadLine/FileIsEOF) - or even CFFILE with action="read".

```
<cfset variables.content = FileRead("mapping/static_1.txt")>
<cfoutput>
    #variables.content#
</cfoutput>
```

There's no point using CFINCLUDE if there's no CFML/CFScript to process.

Comment: Thanks Lucas. I'm new to CF and thought that <cfinclude> do no calculation to .txt  <cffile> is the one that do the job.

Comment: Chanon, just to confirm/clarify, cfinclude treats all files as if they were .cfm files, regardless of their extension (and there are times when that's useful, but obviously this isn't one of them). :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't *need* to cache any compiled class files at all: there's a setting in CFAdmin to switch this caching off (on the Cache page: "Save Class Files").  Those cached files are only really a benefit at server start-up time: it saves files being re-compiled when they're first accessed.  This overhead is neglible, really.  It used to be considerable back in the days of CFMX6 & 7, but not so much since then.

There is - as far as I know - no way to pick & choose which files have their compiled classes saved.  It's all or nothing.

What one could do, I suppose, is to switch the setting on, compile all the apps "main" files so their classes are saved, then switch the setting off.  One would need to repeat this process whenever one adds new files to the application though.  Still: that's not such a hardship.

But I see no benefit in having these files saved at all, these days.

Comment: Hi Adam, my hosting support do not recommend disable caches all together.

Anyway, I came out with a simple solution using <cffile> instead of <cfinclude>.

When using <cffile> server will not execute each lines and create cache. Instead, it just grab the whole chuck of file and put it in variable.

However, thanks anyway :)

Comment: I'd like to see their reasoning for this.  But anyway, what*ever*.  I reckon @Lucas's answer to take file-read / variable output approach is a better solution to your issue, if not a direct answer to your question.